# APOC procedure for XML by JavaAPI

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm using Neo4J API and I need to import an XML file.
On Neo4j I successfully use the following procedure:

```
call
apoc.xml.import("myfile.xml")
yield node
return node;
```

but I do not know how to reproduce this function by Java API.
As far as I know I have to use the *procedures* library, but since each function is buil-in I do not know how to reproduce this one. In the documentation is not mentioned, there are just few examples.
So, is there a way to do the same by Java API?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want ... If I understood, you have a cypher query that works, and you want to do the same with Neo4j API (in embedded mode ?). So what you are searching is how to execute a cypher query with the Java API ?

Comment: Exactly. My function (apoc.xml.import) is already in APOC, but I do not know how to call it from NEO4j Java API.